# PHP strpos() can't get the position of the string from file_get_contents() of SVG file

Tags: php, xml, svg

I try use `strpos()` to find position of 'xml' string from another string from `file_get_content('svgFile');` But I don't get any result using from `strpos()` as below:

```php
<?php
//////////Coding as below:
$string = file_get_contents('../../svg/templates/svgFile.svg');
$string = ' '.$string;
echo $string; // First echo 
$find_string = 'xml';
$position = strpos($string, $find_string);
echo $position; // Second echo
```

```html
//Result of first echo from above: ��
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 11.0, SVG Export Plug-In -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd" [ <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
<!ENTITY ns_svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<!ENTITY ns_xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">]>
<svg xmlns="&ns_svg;" xmlns:xlink="&ns_xlink;" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" width="285" height="172" viewBox="-0.5 -0.422 285 172" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs></defs>
  <g>
    <path fill="#8ADBFF" stroke="#000000" d="M0.5,0.5v170.078h283.465V0.5H0.5z M193.401,32.68l-6.279,10.906l-4.837-11.618 l-12.313-2.601l9.554-8.19l-1.331-12.513l10.742,6.555l11.489-5.132l-2.915,12.241l8.433,9.342L193.401,32.68z M235.543,39.43 l-7.775-3.548l-7.327,4.395l0.971-8.49l-6.444-5.613l8.375-1.699l3.348-7.863l4.204,7.438l8.514,0.755l-5.778,6.297L235.543,39.43 z M254.58,54.631l-3.269-5.78l-6.614-0.583l4.487-4.895l-1.489-6.472l6.042,2.755l5.695-3.416l-0.753,6.599l5.007,4.359 l-6.508,1.323L254.58,54.631z M271.189,71.928l-4.689-1.037l-3.512,3.275l-0.463-4.78l-4.199-2.327l4.401-1.918l0.917-4.714 l3.185,3.594l4.766-0.585l-2.435,4.141L271.189,71.928z"
    />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 24.1665 129.832)">
      <tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'OCRAStd'" font-size="23">OCR A Std 23pt</tspan>
    </text>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 24.1665 85.4995)">
      <tspan x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'SegoePrint'" font-size="23">Segoe p</tspan>
      <tspan x="88.889" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'SegoePrint'" font-size="23">r</tspan>
      <tspan x="100.827" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'SegoePrint'" font-size="23">int 23pt</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>


//Result of second echo from above show empty. why??????
```

Comment: But there is no "xml" in your fist echo of the string, therefore there is nothing to be printed, it's null.

Comment: SVG is an XML format. Any reason you're node using an XML library?

Answer (score 0):

strpos returns `false` when the find_string is not found at all.

In your example you search for "xml" but the first output shows that there is not "xml" in your string. thus strpos retursn `false`. When you echo false it shows nothing. thus you can't see the result.

try:

```
if($position){echo "true";}else{echo "false";}
```

and see the result of that.

Comment: Sry, I have corrected my string. It should have 'xml' inside.

Comment: ok. you could try the if anyway. That might help to get closer to the cause of the problem.

Comment: it still return false. The funny thing is, if I change $find_string = 'xml' to be $find_string = 'x'. than It work find.

Comment: you should check the output if it's acctually "xml" or if there are hidden symbols in it. It might be that the program you used to make the svg-file added symboly you can't see in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a SVG file with `file_get_contents`. `file_get_contents` opens a binary file and the string function you later on use (`strpos`) is a binary string function.

However an SVG file is an XML file and the two standard encodings of an XML file are UTF-8 and UTF-16. And if you look closely at the first output we can see the following at the beginning:

```
//Result of first echo from above: ��
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
```

The XML Declaration here says the file is UTF-16 encoded.

If we assume this information given is correct and the SVG file indeed is UTF-16 encoded, the PHP code

```
$find_string = 'xml';
$position = strpos($string, $find_string);
```

must return `false` from `strpos` because the binary (string) sequence "`xml`" is not part of the file. The file is UTF-16 and not UTF-8 encoded. Let's see the string "`xml`" in the different encodings:

```
Encoding             PHP String             Displayed As

UTF-8                "xml"                  xml
UTF-16               "x\0m\0l\0"            xml
UTF-16 (with BOM)    "\xFF\xFEx\0m\0l\0"    ��xml
```

As this comparison table shows, the string `'xml'` is never available when the file is UTF-16 encoded. You must actually look for `"x\0m\0l\0"` which is with one NUL-byte after each of the three letters.

Fundamentally you're just experiencing here that strings in PHP are binary and when you output them to the browser, the browser does hide some characters, here the NUL characters of which there are many in the file.